# Registering Automapper with Unity

Tags: unity-container, automapper

I'm trying to register automapper 3.2.1 with unity 3.0.1304.1. I have tried the usual registration answers from StackOverflow, with no luck. Any clue how to properly register the latest automapper with unity? Did something change in the most recent version? Code and exception below:

---

**Registering like this:**

```
container.RegisterType<ConfigurationStore, ConfigurationStore>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(typeof(ITypeMapFactory), MapperRegistry.Mappers));
container.RegisterType<IConfigurationProvider, ConfigurationStore>();
container.RegisterType<IConfiguration, ConfigurationStore>();
container.RegisterType<IMappingEngine, MappingEngine>();
container.RegisterType<ITypeMapFactory, TypeMapFactory>();
```

---

**Then I receive the following error:**

The type IDictionary`2 does not have an accessible constructor.

---

**At the time, it is resolving this:**

```
  Resolving AutoMapper.MappingEngine,(none) (mapped from AutoMapper.IMappingEngine, (none))
  Resolving parameter "objectMapperCache" of constructor AutoMapper.MappingEngine(AutoMapper.IConfigurationProvider configurationProvider, AutoMapper.Internal.IDictionary`2[[AutoMapper.Impl.TypePair, AutoMapper, Version=3.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=be96cd2c38ef1005],[AutoMapper.IObjectMapper, AutoMapper, Version=3.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=be96cd2c38ef1005]] objectMapperCache, System.Func`2[[System.Type, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] serviceCtor)
    Resolving AutoMapper.Internal.IDictionary`2[AutoMapper.Impl.TypePair,AutoMapper.IObjectMapper],(none)
```

Comment: This is why you really shouldn't try to register public types belonging to 3rd party frameworks. Anyway, what's stopping you from providing a layer of abstraction over the top of AutoMapper and registering that instead?

Comment: I hear you...I was just trying to get this working because so many other people on SO had said they had it working. Nothing wrong with wrapping it, I suppose that's the way I'll go. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

Try using InjectionConstructor in IMappingEngine registration like this:

```
container.RegisterType<IMappingEngine, MappingEngine>(new InjectionConstructor(typeof(IConfigurationProvider)));
```

Comment: Thanks, I might try this at some point...I ended up putting an adapter on the mapping engine that I mock out instead.

Comment: The reason you are receiving such exception is that Unity tries to resolve type by using its constructor with maximum parameters available (with 2 in your case). By using InjectionConstructor you instruct Unity to use specific constructor instead.